# Is it possible to resize a cropped 2D seismic line in a window using mouse?

Tags: petrel

I have a cropped 2D line in the Input tree. I just want to resize it the same way I usually do with a 3D line (using mouse in the 3D window), but currently I can change the boundaries only in the settings dialog of the seismic 2D collection. It it possible?

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 1):

This is really a Petrel user issue, not Ocean SDK. I do not believe you can perform this operation in Petrel on a 2D line as you wish to. It can only be done through Settings as you say.